# Tracking usage of an IPhone/Android app

Tags: android, iphone, facebook

I'm part of a development team for an IPhone/Android app. 
So far, we've implemented a basic Facebook functionality in the apps (permissions,post on wall).

We want to track the usage of the Facebook functions separated by the two platforms. 
In other words, we want to know how much of the posts are coming from Android and how much are from the IPhone version.

Is there anything in the Facebook api (a tag flag) that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't available in Facebook insights.  You would have to build the tracking and analytics for this yourself. For example, if someone successfully makes a wall post via your application, you would log this event to your server with the users device information.  You could also track this with Google Analytics SDK for [iOS](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/) or [Android](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a separate facebook app for iphone and a separate facebook app for android. You will have usage reports in insights. There are obviously different users for these apps, so you can manage them separately, make updates, etc.